# How to backup my app data if my phone is not rooted?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, backup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Full Backup of non-rooted devices](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28296/full-backup-of-non-rooted-devices)

I'm going to flash (format) my Samsung Galaxy S2 (both the external sd and internal sd) . My phone is not rooted. But there are some app's data that i want to backup before formatting.Those are some of my games' progress,Mozilla Firefox's history,bookmarks etc,Opera Mini history etc. , and the songs i tagged in Shazam . How am i supposed to do that since i know that you can't backup app data such as game progress if your phone is not rooted ?  Also I can't access those apps, whenever I open them they constantly crash, this started 1 week ago, that's why im gonna flash my device (but this is another thread's subject). I would appreciate any help.

Comment: After 2 years I stumbled upon this question that I asked and it made me smile :) Anyone who comes up to this question today, just use [Helium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.backup). It backups your app data (game progress etc.) without root. I wish I knew this 2 years before :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Android sdk. It includes something called adb. Here is a link to a previous question. [Full Backup of non-rooted devices](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28296/full-backup-of-non-rooted-devices/37687#37687) .Here is a list of all adb commands. http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/android/devguide/guide/developing/tools/android_adb_commandsummary.html